# Framework selection for New web project

Tags: php, codeigniter, asp.net-mvc-4, yii, frameworks

We are starting a new web application project. We have expertise with DotNet and PHP.

This project will be a SAAS, and we may go for cloud services in future. Considering this and cost of mysql and SQL server, we are thinking of adopting PHP development for that project.

If we go for PHP, what framework we should use.

1 - Codeigniter (we have good expirence of that and developed 2-3 small - medium scale project using this)

2 - YII (heard a lot about it, and some of my fellow colleagues are recommneding it, as it has good code generation, unit testing and object orientation support than codeigniter)

3 - Any other framework?

We will be developing restfull apis, which will be communicated by web and mobile applications.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), it's a wonderful PHP framework.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Yii** at my full time job for almost 3 years and I will try to give you the pros and cons

**Pros:**

- Very fast in building minimal viable product (code generators helps here)
- Strong MVC structure, meaning when I want to find something in project I can blindly find it even if my colleague wrote it
- RBAC is fairly easy to implement and use
- Very extendable. Just find a class that you want to improve and extend it
- I think Yii is trying so hard to be like Ruby on Rails, which is a good thing, but PHP is the limiting factor

**Cons:**

- Helper methods for generating html controls that will send ajax request are a mess. I ended up writing my own custom JavaScript every time
- No full restful api out of the box. There are some extensions, but I never tried them. I just got used to update my content via POST
- Active Record lack a bit when you try to save multiple models that are in relation. You have to write your own transaction and everything, but it's manageable
- And the biggest flaw for me is small community. Yes, for some simple things you will find what you want in the first 3 google links, but eventually you will stuck your head with some complex task and you will feel all alone. Maybe I'm just spoiled with Rails, anything you can think of there is a gem (extension) for it

I never tried .NET nor Codeigniter so I will not speak of those two.

When you choose a framework keep in mind your deadlines and how much time you will have to dive into a new thing. If you have enough time/enthusiasm to learn new thing I would suggest you to try Ruby on Rails. I find it incomparably better then Yii in almost every way.

I hope this helped a bit, and good luck with your project